# Confused about behavior of Observable

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I have a service with a method that returns an Observable

```
SecurityService {
    canAccess():Observable<boolean> {...}
```

I use this in a couple different places, in a canActivate guard and w/in components as well.

Here's my canActivate method:

```
canActivate(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.securityService.canAccess(route.data['securityScreenId'],'screen','NA').first().map(result => {
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    });
}
```

When I look at the browser console, I see this output:

```
ScalarObservable {_isScalar: true, value: true, scheduler: null}
```

And when I apply this guard to a route, the routing is cancelled and the route's component doesn't load.

I thought that map was supposed to take the response of the observable being mapped, and then transform it based on the method passed to map.  So in my method, shouldn't the result of console.log just be true, instead of the ScalarObservable?

Comment: I have the same method when I use canActivate, are you getting any other exceptions in your logs ? What happens if you just return true, can you access the route ?

Comment: So I found the problem.  I was going through all the code that implements my canAccess method (lots of services that look up info and then check to see if the user has sufficient privileges) and I found one place where, in my .map method, I was returning Observable.of(true) instead of just true.  When I fixed that, everything started to work like I was expecting it to.


I'm still curious about what exactly a ScalarObservable is and how/when it's used.

Answer (score 0):

```
canActivate(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
return this.securityService.canAccess(route.data['securityScreenId'],'screen','NA').first().subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
    return result;
});
```

}

AFAIK Observables do not execute until you subscribe.